# Yii force lowercase column names in Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, yii, pdo

I found it and write here if it will be useful for someone. By default Yii framework uses PDO and pdo serves oracle column names in uppercase. To force returning them in lowercase U have to create custom connection and set PDO attribute, like:

```
class COraConnection extends CDbConnection
{
        protected function initConnection($pdo)
        {
                parent::initConnection($pdo);
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
      ...             
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked, that U can set it directly  on your db, without creating custom CDbConnection.
Say your oracle connection name in main.php is

```
'dbora' => array(
     'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'oci:dbname=192.168.0.1:1521/shop;charset=CL8MSWIN1251',
        'username' => 'dbuser',
        'password' => 'dbpwd',
      ),
```

Just write it where U need it:

```
$db = Yii::app()->dbora;
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
```